# Is there a maximum width a webpage can be?

Tags: html

I'm planning a page where things are repeatedly appended horizontally. Will there be a point where elements can no longer be appended, because of a maximum page width?

Comment: uh, keep going to find it out :)

Comment: There is a question about this somewhere on SO, but I can't find it, in which indeed hard limits were found for IE and Firefox, but they were insanely high.

Comment: The real limit is how far your users are willing to scroll. I'm willing to be that's **not very far**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will probably be some implementation specific limit to how wide the page can be or to how many elements you can have on a page, but there will be a limit you will hit long before then: the limit to how patient your user is when scrolling, or the amount of elements you can load before your page becomes too slow.

You might want to look at a paging solution and/or loading and unloading elements dynamically.

Comment: Indeed there is a hard limit: the amount of memory your computer has (even when including swap etc.), and far more likely limits in the browser. But no sane web app or webpage would ever hit such a limit.