# <div> width crashes iPad's iOS5 Safari browser

Tags: css, ipad, safari, html

I have a swipeable carousel-like web app consisting of ten 1024px wide slides. When I set the content layer width to 10240px, Safari crashes intermittently when app loads.  Something like this:

```
<div id="view" style="width:1024px;height:748px;overflow:hidden">
   <div id="content" style="width:10240px;height:748px;">
     content 
   </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how to handle such a width for iPad's Safari? Is there a limit to how wide of a content the browser can handle?

Thanks.

Comment: I was able to zero down some more on this. It seems to be crashing when translate3D property is applied so the full content css looks like this: 

<div id="content" style="width:10240px;height:748px;-webkit-transition-duration:500ms">

... Then, I apply transormation with jQuery by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been thinking about this question since I first read it. I'm sure I've seen a post here with someone having a sort-of-similar problem when making a huge images grid (it reached certain width and it crashed). I looked for info regarding maximum width in browsers in stackoverflow. Here:

[HTML Maximum Browser Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6981814/html-maximum-browser-width) (firefox and chrome 12.000px, unspecified browser 9.000px)

[Is there a maximum width a webpage can be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126313/is-there-a-maximum-width-a-webpage-can-be) (depends on the amount of memory your device has).

I think the post I'm talking about got this problem around 9.000px. Why don't you try with smaller images (890px each), just to test, and see if you got the same issue. And post the results, with more and more huge websites this question can be very useful to other people.

Comment: I was able to zero down some more on this. It seems to be crashing when translate3D property is applied so the full content css looks like this: 

<div id="content" style="width:10240px;height:748px;-webkit-transition-duration:500ms">

Then, I apply transformation with jQuery by

$('#content').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate3D(' + x + 'px,' + y + 'px, 0px)');